# How to trade in Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

How do I trade or add friends in Pokemon Go? Or is it not possible yet? For instance, each Pokemon has a "Transfer" option, but it seems that only gives the Pokemon to the professor, not to other players.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trading is coming to Pokemon Go in the next update with the new friend feature. You will be able to trade Pokemon with a friend that is in close proximity with you. The trade will cost stardust and Pokemon IVs will change in the trade. The higher your friend level with another player is the less stardust trading costs and the less IVs will be able to alter. If the Pokemon is caught further that 100km from the trade location trading will give extra candies. This answer is based on [Rankedboosts summary](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/trading/) of the coming features.

Comment: Yep, trading is available now with the behavior described above. See Niantic's support page for more details: https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001518407-Trading-Pok%C3%A9mon

Answer (score 19):

You cannot currently trade Pokémon between players in Pokémon Go. This may change in the future, but is not an option now.

Answer (score 0):

You cant trade yet but they did put in in the trailer so hopefully they make tradeing a thing

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer...